# Is there any leak memory tracing SDK for Swift on iOs like Leak Candy ( Android )

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, swift4, instruments, leakcanary

Is there any SDK for leak memory on iOs for
I used Allocation & Leaks instrument for my Swift project but it usually crash after some minutes running on devices.
Thank you!

Comment: Instead of asking us for a tool, describe your leak and ask about that.

Answer (score 2):

Run the app so that you get into the state where you suspect a leak, and switch to the Memory Graph debugger. If there's a leak, it will tell you instantly.

In this screen shot, a Dog and a Cat are retaining each other.

[image]

If you also turn on Malloc Stack in your scheme, the Memory Graph debugger gives you a backtrace.

[image]